# Is it acceptable for an iPhone application to require a login on first startup?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Will Apple accept an application that requires a login to an online account the first time it boots?  I'd like use this to link the user to an online highscores system for a game and for some analytic purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's many, many games that do this already. In fact when you submit your app for testing, there's an optional text field that lets you provide the test engineer with a pre-existing test account name & password.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I like the idea of requiring a login account.  Optional logins are fine, but requiring such activity is too much of a hassle or privacy concern for some people.

As a consumer, I like having the option to opt out of signing into such services.  I would recommend supporting your customers' prerogative to choose anonymity or privacy over the benefit of being eligible for the high score system.

Comment: +1 - completely agree. If i'm not excited about a game already, sometimes a crappy signup system is enough to make me delete the game. I like the way both plus and openfeint allow you to "skip the signup and miss out on awesome features"